# Creating an entity relationship diagram

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship

I've created this ERD:

[image: img]

But now I want to add some more information to my diagram, but I do not how I should do that.

I want to modify my previous ERD, I need to register what recipe was made by what chef in each program. Also, I want to identify what ingredient and tool were used in each step of the recipe.

Comment: You can relate `Ingredient` and `Tool` to `Steps` instead of `Recipe`. I don't understand what relationship(s) you want between `Recipe`, `Chef` and `Program`. Try describing it in more detail or giving examples.

Comment: @reaanb i wanna "store" what recipe was made by what chef.. i mean for example chef1 --->hamburgers/chef2--->french fries and so on. AND i wanna store what ingredient and tool were used in each recipe (in this case hamburgers and french fries)  and the program. Do you understand me? :S

Comment: Your diagram already associates chefs with recipes. It sounds like you just need to change `By` into a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: @reaanb What should i do then pal?

Answer (score 0):

I think implementing your Entity Relationship Diagram into Microsoft Access can be a good start. You've clearly defined the relations between each entity and have declared attributes for each entity. I would say that you first make each entity into a table in MS Access then add the fields and set up the relationships and see how the work together.

Make sure that your relationships are working before you start filling the database with records.

Comment: Mate, i do not understand how should i complete my ERD with the extra information :S

Comment: Note that "Relationships" in MS Access refer to FK constraints, not ER relationships.

Comment: @programming_always you can add more information to your ERD by adding more circles to each rectangle and adding necessary names relating to that specific rectangle.